# Парсинг информации большого объема с сайта

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Нужно спарсить очень много информации с сайта на свой сайт и сохранить в базу. Скрипт для этого уже готов. 
Вопрос: Каким образом можно заставить "засыпать" скрипт на некоторое время и после снова продолжать работу. Это для того чтобы сервер не выдавал ошибку, так как парсеру нужно работать не один час.

Comment: Запускайте скрипт по крону и за один запуск обрабатывайте ограниченное количество страниц.

Comment: @Visman а как-то автоматизировать этот процесс нельзя? чтобы в дальнейшем работал без вмешательства

Comment: Так у вас скрипт и будет работать без вашего вмешательства.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно просто в определенное время работы скрипта вызывать функцию [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php):

```
sleep(10); //10 - кол-во секунд
```

Но тогда учтите что нужно сказать чтобы скрипт работал "вечно", можно к примеру вот так:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Документация по функции `set_time_limit`: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php

UPD. Вспомнил ещё про возможность изменения времени только в определенном скрипте:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Что лучше я не знаю если честно.

Comment: set_time_limit(0); - это указывать в исполняемом файле?

Comment: @Денис да, можно в конфигах php, но тогда это будет на все скрипты, а вам только 1 нужен